# Is it possible to set width of the JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a `JFrame` which is resizeable. I've added my `JTextPane` to it, within a `JScrollbar`.

Now I want to fix the width of my `JTextPane`, in order to when I add new text, if it was longer than width of my `JTextPane` wrap the text! My `JTextPane` has a `StyledDocument`.

Comment: Post your code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Add the `JTextPane` to a `JScrollPane`. The text will wrap automatically when the width of the text pane is reached.